# how to set everything inside a structure to 0?

Tags: c++, database, struct

I have a structure that has 3 different types of values in it (char, float, int).......I need to set everything to 0 at the beginning of the program. How do I do that?

Comment: the structure is used in an Array if that changes anything

Comment: You can edit your question to add that information. It would be good if you added a line of code showing how it is used in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 struct A
 {
   int a;
   char b;
   float c;
 };
```

`struct A` is an aggregate, built-in types initialized to `0`.  You can initialize to A in two ways:

```
//Class method pass to function
int main() 
{
  A a = {};      // initialize single A to 0
  A b = A();     // same effort
  A c[10] = {};  // initialize array to 0

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Ivaylo Aggregate initialization has existed since ever.

Comment: @billz strangely this makes some of the datas 0 and keeps the rest of the datas as they were (preset into memory location)

Comment: @MokammelHossainSanju how do you mean 'the rest of the datas as they were'?

Comment: @billz structure is put into an array that means from your example A a[]....The array is 10 characters long and when I print everything, some of the values are 0 but others have dumped memory data on them.

Comment: @MokammelHossainSanju with array, it's different story, see my updated answer

Comment: is *A b = b();* a typo?  because it wouldn't build like that...  do you mean A b= A();

Answer (score 6):

There are two usual ways:

```
A a = A();
```

or

```
A a = {};
```

The first has the advantage that if you later provide
constructor, it still works (as long as you provide a default
constructor).

With regards to the suggestion to use `memset`: `memset` is only
guaranteed to work for integral types.  I can't imagine it not
working for a `float`, but formally, it's not guaranteed.  And
of course, if you later modify the `struct`, it might stop
working.  It is a solution to avoid.

Comment: For an array, you'd have to use the second form.  But if you use `std::vector<A>`, it will do the equivalent of the first on every element (unless you provide it with something different to copy).

Comment: Thanx a lot, I have been trying that, but I guess I need to do that when I declare my global custom variable.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways:

1. Use initializer `mystruct x = { '\0', 0.0f, 0 };`
2. Use `mystruct x; memset(&x, 0, sizeof(x));`
3. Write a function (or, in C++, a constructor) that sets each value to zero.

Generally, first one is the most obvious, but if you have a large number of structs, then you may find either of option 2 or 3 more suitable.

Note: using `memset` is ONLY safe on data structures that ONLY contain data. In C++, a `struct` and a `class` are almost identical, and a `struct` that has member functions, has other `struct` or `class` members or has inherited from another `class` or `struct`, will definitely not be safe to use `memset` on. And of course, this is particularly dangerous if you start out with a plain data `struct`, and then ADD functionality into the `struct` that "breaks" the 'only data' promise.

Comment: I strongly suggest you avoid using method 2. While it is safe for as long as your `struct` remains plain old data; getting used to using `memset` to zero things is asking for trouble in the future.

Comment: @JackAidley: Thanks for pointing that out. I've added a note to the effect.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of a [constructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_%28object-oriented_programming%29#C.2B.2B) to initialise all of your elements. So you will be able not just to use 0 maybe also other values.

```
 struct A
 {
   int a;
   char b;
   float c;
   A(int _a=0,char _b=0,float _c=0.0) : a(_a), b(_b), c(_c) {}
 };

int main() 
{
  A a;
  // work with a
  return 0;
}
```